# Can Excel interpret the URLs in my CSV as hyperlinks?

Tags: excel, csv, hyperlink

Can Excel interpret the URLs in my CSV as hyperlinks? If so, how?

Comment: This answer is also useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7572268/how-to-encode-a-hyperlink-in-csv-formatted-file

Answer (score 96, accepted):

You can actually do this and have Excel show a clickable link.  Use this format in the CSV file:

```
=HYPERLINK("URL")
```

So the CSV would look like:

```
1,23.4,=HYPERLINK("http://www.google.com")
```

However, I'm trying to get some links with commas in them to work properly and it doesn't look like there's a way to escape them and still have Excel make the link clickable.

Does anyone know how?

Comment: The proposed solutions together with Jim's and Hemans' additions work well. However the formula is different for different languages (ie =LIEN_HYPERTEXTE("...") for French. Basically this solution works only in English Excel (or any other single language)

Comment: You can wrap any CSV field with "quotes" and then you can add as commas and quotes (using ""):

`field1,"field2","field3,with ""commas"""` should be interpreted by valid CSV readers as three fields.

It's a good idea to use an existing CSV reader/writer library to deal with these edge cases.

Comment: This seems to be working for LibreOffice 5.1.6 as well.

Comment: Hi.. Thanks for this, it works for csv, but my only concern is its not changing color of the hyperlink. By default hyperlink should be either blue in clor or underlined. Can anyone help me here please.

Answer (score 18):

With embedding the hyperlink function you need to watch the quotes. Below is an example of a CSV file created that lists an error and a link to view the documentation on the method that failed. (Bit esoteric but that's what I am working on)

```
"Details","Failing Method (click to view)"
"Method failed","=HYPERLINK(""http://some_url_with_documentation"",""Method_name"")"
```

Comment: The arguments of HYPERLINK() must be separated with a semicolon, not by a comma, at least in my (German) version of Excel 2007.

Comment: @cmarqu I think it depends on the list separator that your system is using.  The German locale by default uses ; as the list separator, and this has to be used as the separator in CSV files (ironic given the "Comma-Separated Values" acronym) and as the argument-separator in Excel formulae.  For other locales like US English the default is the comma.  So basically you have to use the same separator that you're using to separate cells in the CSV file.  That's what I found by testing both comma and semi-colon in a couple of versions of Excel with different settings anyway.

Answer (score 16):

I read all of these answers and some others but it still took a while to work it out in Excel 2014.

The result in the csv should look like this

```
"=HYPERLINK(""http://www.Google.com"",""Google"")"
```

Note: If you are trying to set this from MSSQL server then

```
'"=HYPERLINK(""http://www.' + baseurl + '.com"",""' + baseurl + '"")"' AS url
```

Answer (score 8):

you can URL Encode your commas inside the URL so the URL is not split across multiple cells.

Just replace commas with %2c

http://www.xyz.com/file,comma.pdf

becomes

=hyperlink("http://www.xyz.com/file%2ccomma.pdf")

Comment: Thanks for the answer, It really works. I tried many solutions but none of them worked.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, but it's not possible to link them automatically. CSV files are just text files - whatever opens and reads them is responsible for allowing you to click the link.

---

As to how Excel seems to handle CSV files - everything between commas is interpreted as if it already had been typed into the cell. Therefore, the CSV file containing `="http://google.com",=A1` will display as `http://google.com,http://google.com` in Excel. It's important to note, however, that hyperlinks in Excel are metadata, and not the result of anything in the actual cell (ie, a hyperlinked cell to Google still contains `http://google.com` not `<a>http://google.com</a>` or anything of that sort.)

Since that's the case, and all metadata is lost when converting to a CSV, it's impossible to tell Excel you wish for something to be hyperlinked merely by changing the cell value. Normally, Excel interprets your input when you hit 'Enter' and links URLs then, but since CSV data is not being entered, but rather already exists, this does not happen.

Your best bet is to write some sort of addon or macro to run when you open up a CSV which parses every cell and hyperlinks them if they match a URL format.

Comment: Ah, that's an important distinction. I don't think it's possible, no.

Comment: this is not the answer, see below. You can use =HYPERLINK("URL")

Comment: This is not correct, you can do `"=HYPERLINK(""http://www.google.com"")"` as explained below, you just need to have all those quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Use this format:

```
=HYPERLINK(""<URL>"";""<LABEL>"")
```

e.g.:

```
=HYPERLINK(""http://stackoverflow.com"";""I love stackoverflow!"")
```

*P.S. The same format works in LibreOffice Calc as well.*

Answer (score 0):

"=HYPERLINK(\"\" " + "http://www.mywebsite.com"+ "\"\")"
use this format before writing to CSV.

Answer (score 0):

As described above, `"=HYPERLINK(""http://www.google.com"", ""Google"")"` is what worked for me.

However, In Excel Version 2204 Click to Run, I couldn't have leading white space.

For example;

`FirstName, "=HYPERLINK(""http://www.google.com"", ""Google"")"` **fails**
`FirstName,"=HYPERLINK(""http://www.google.com"", ""Google"")"` **success**

Answer (score -1):

The issue here for me was that because a .CSV by it's nature is Comma separated, any commas in the text file are interpreted as separators. It worked for me by using tab characters as separators, saving it as a .TXT file so that when opened in EXCEL you choose the TAB character rather than ','.

In the text file …

**## ensure that the file is TAB separated
Item 1  A file Name data.txt

Item 2  Col 2   =HYPERLINK("http:\www.ilexuk.com","ILEX")**

"ILEX" then is shown in the cell and "http:\www.ilexuk.com" is the hyperlink for the cell.