# How to encode a hyperlink in CSV formatted file?

Tags: csv, hyperlink, encode

When I try to encode a HTML anchor link in CSV file cell it becomes corrupted and not readable by Excel.

Is there some sort of non-HTML solution or format to encode a hyperlink in CSV file cell?

Comment: This is a bit more explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6563091/can-excel-interpret-the-urls-in-my-csv-as-hyperlinks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6563091/can-excel-interpret-the-urls-in-my-csv-as-hyperlinks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A CSV file is simply text - it's up to the loading program how it chooses to interpret the text.

If Excel is complaining when you feed it `"<a href=\"blah\">Link</a>", "another cell"` then try just having the raw URL and you might find Excel will automagically turn it into a link.

But in general Excel doesn't process HTML, so expecting it render HTML from a CSV file is asking too much.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but is there any kind of Excel URL format to force it make link from URL? If no, then I'll try just to send raw URL

Answer (score 87):

For when automagicalism doesn't work, and you're definitely using Excel, use this as the field content.

```
=HYPERLINK("http://stackoverflow.com")
```

Comment: this, and Bob Mulder's answer both work in OpenOffice as well.

Comment: this even works with google spreadsheets, be aware that you can also pass a second parameter for the link name: `=HYPERLINK("http://stackoverflow.com", "so.com")`

Comment: The link text does not seem to work when importing a CSV to LibreOffice 5.1

Comment: For relative file paths: ```=HYPERLINK("./folder/file.ext", "file.ext")```

Comment: After opening the file in Excel, is there a way to save the file back to CSV without Excel complaining of it containing some non CSV feature and removing them? (it will strip the "=HYPERLINK" part and only leave the address, which means that next time you open the file the hyperlink functionality is gone)

Answer (score 29):

This worked for me:

1. Use the `=HYPERLINK` function, the first parameter is the web link, the second is the cell value.
2. Put `"` quotes around the entire function.
3. Escape the internal quotes within the function with two sets of quotes, i.e., `""`

Here's a four-column comma-delimited `example.csv`:

```
5,6,"=HYPERLINK(""http://www.yahoo.com"";""See Yahoo"")",8
```

When a spreadsheet program (LibreOffice, etc.) opens this .csv, it creates an active link for you.

Comment: Use comma instead of ; like this
"=HYPERLINK(""http://www.yahoo.com"",""See Yahoo"")"

Comment: I just tried this with the latest Excel on my Mac. The "," delimiter worked, but the ";" did not. Also, the link is not highlighted or underlined, so a user would not know that it's clickable. Any way to do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

What worked for me in Excel 2003 - output to your CSV the statement:

```
CELLVALUE="=HYPERLINK("+QM+URLCONTENTS+QM+";"+QM+"URLDISPLAYNAME"+QM+")"
```

- note the semicolon `;` use in the hyperlink. I've found the comma not to work for me in Excel 2003.
- Depending on the script or language you use quotemarks could be handled differently. The cellvalue you put into the CSV before you import it into Excel should look exactly like this: **`"=HYPERLINK("URLCONTENTS";"URLDISPLAYNAME")"`**

where:

- `CELLVALUE` is the output written to the CSV
- `QM` is the ASCII value of `["]` -> (ASCII 34)
- `URLCONTENTS` is the full URL to the page you want to link to.
  -`URLDISPLAYNAME` is the text you see in the Excel cell.

You can also use relative paths and set a base location in Excel.

> File/Properties > Tab Summary > Field Hyperlink Base.

Use as fieldvalue something like `http://www.SITENAME.com/SUB_LOCATION/../SUB_LOCATION` that sets your starting point so you can click it in Excel. Of course, you don't have to use SUB_LOCATIONs if the sitename itself already will resolve successfully for your relative path.

What I couldn't find is how to make the links automatically underlined in Excel. From other tips found [in this article](http://blog.ayaz.pk/2009/06/24/creating-click-able-hyper-links-in-csv-files-programmatically/#comment-835):

> Format manually all linkcells as underlined and darkblue (for example) and then the standard functionality appears with already visited links turning into another color.

Comment: Whether to use a comma or a semicolon as the argument separator in the formula depends on your system settings.  In Windows Control Panel you can set the list separator as comma or semicolon, and that dictates what Excel expects as both the cell separator in CSV files and as the argument separator in formulae.  I tested this in Excel 2003 with both list separator settings and found that, in the formula, you need to use the list separator as the argument separator if you want it to display correctly in Excel.

Comment: If you using "csv" in python:  following worked for me:                                      `code old_row['column_name'] = "=HYPERLINK(\"http://www.yahoo.com\" + "," + "\"" + "friendly_name"  + "\"" + ")"    `                                                          I am reading it in Excel 2010, and "," works instead of ";".