# How to format HYPERLINK in csv-file for Excel import using friendly name

Tags: excel, csv, hyperlink

I have a csv-file that looks something like this:

```
value1;value2;=HYPERLINK("http://somelink";"linkdisplay");value3
```

When I import this to Excel 2013, the csv is split on semicolon, also splitting the hyperlink between the link and the friendly text. I have attempted to change List separator on Windows to comma, that actually also changed the requirements for the hyperlink to split the friendly text with a comma, so no luck there. Attempted to add quotes as mentioned in [How to encode a hyperlink in CSV formatted file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7572268/how-to-encode-a-hyperlink-in-csv-formatted-file), that did not work for me.

Someone got a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For file:

```
String hyperlinks = "\"=HYPERLINK(\"\"file://" + DocumentDataType.strDirectoy + docName + "\"\",\"\""+ DocumentDataType.strDirectoy + docName+ "\"\")\"" + ",";
```

For website:

```
String hyperlinks_SourcePath = "\"=HYPERLINK(\"\"http://" +ipAddress+":"+portNumber+"/WorkplaceXT"+ "\"\",\"\""+sourcePathFinal+ "\"\")\"" + ",";
```

Comment: Thank you! This totally solved my problem. Just had to change the comma in your code to semi colon, and now it works like a charm!
`code`
String.format("\"=HYPERLINK(\"\"" + "%s/%s" + "\"\";\"\""+ "%s" + "\"\")\"", new Object[]{basePath, link, displayText});
`code`

Answer (score 0):

I found the selected answer here a bit confusing.

Just use the excel function `hyperlink(link_location, optional_friendly_name)`

Here is how I did it in php:

```
$link = '=hyperlink("' . $web_address . '","' . $visible_name . '")';
```

This produces something like this:

```
=hyperlink("http://example.com/students?student_id=10","View")
```