# How to convert HTML column links as html text?

Tags: excel

I'm having an excel sheet with 7 columns and out of which 2 columns have URL links. for example Listen will the text shown in the excel sheet which has an URL embedded with it and you can see the below link on Edit Hyperlink

Example, http://ctrial.in/wp-content/uploads/25_10_09_Morning.mp3

So i need to convert it to as html text

Listen

Basically like to convert excel to .csv file and want the links to be coverted as HTML text

Currently when coverted to csv directly removes the links.

Please kindly help me on how to resolve this.

Thanks.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please edit it and give an example for the expected result. What is "HTML text" in your world? How would a link to an MP3 file look in "HTML text"?

Comment: CSV format is just text. Not sure how you want to deal with a link, but [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7572268/how-to-encode-a-hyperlink-in-csv-formatted-file) may be useful.