# Hyperlink in content of CSV file doesn't contains style

Tags: java, csv, hyperlink

Hyperlink in content of CSV file works but style is not appearing on link. I have a .csv file that I was able to put in a hyperlink. When it opens in excel and put your cursor across the cell it shows the little hand and when click will open the hyperlinked document.

I have used `Java` Program to create a CSV file. My Code for hyperlink looks like:

`hyperlink = "=HYPERLINK(\"http://stackoverflow.com\")";`

What I would like to do is make that blue and underline?

Comment: CSV is just plain text with no means of displaying formatting information. The formatting completely depends on the application you are opening the file with.

Comment: Can we do any formatting if we want to open the CSV file with Excel application? I mean, may be on excel side

Comment: Hmm, after some (rather brief) research, I still wasn't able to find a way to change the colouring of csv-fields (even on the Excel side). By the way, here is a similar question - maybe it helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6563091/can-excel-interpret-the-urls-in-my-csv-as-hyperlinks?rq=1
If formatting is truly important to you you might think about directly creating an .XSLX-File instead of CSV. There are Java libraries you can use for that (http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/ for example). This tutorial might be helpful: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaExcel/article.html

Answer (score 0):

Csv file does not support a format to append like styles
The only way is that we can use hyperlink in csv file