# Change display name for hyperlink in csv file while opening through Excel

Tags: java, excel, csv, hyperlink

I have a java program that has been used to generate a CSV file. I have a column which contains link to some web pages. I want to put link on it with custom display name on it.

When I write `=HYPERLINK("http://www.google.com","Google")` on msExcel it gives me desired result. I wanted same from my java program. My program looks as follows:

> res.setContentType("application/csv");
>
> BufferedWriter sbs = new BufferedWriter(res.getWriter());
>
> res.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;
>   filename=\"joblist.csv\"");
>
> StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
>
> String link = "http://www.google.com";
>
> String hyperlink = "=HYPERLINK(\""+link+jo.getId()+"\"\",\"\"Google\")";
>
> sb.append(hyperlink);

I followed this link to add hyperlink on CSV file.
[Can Excel interpret the URLs in my CSV as hyperlinks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6563091/can-excel-interpret-the-urls-in-my-csv-as-hyperlinks)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this

```
"=HYPERLINK(""http://www.google.com"",""google"")","1234","yyyy"
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately CSV is a text file format.
Thus it cannot contain a hyperlink.

Comment: Actually I added hyperlink in CSV file while opening in msExcel by following this link.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6563091/can-excel-interpret-the-urls-in-my-csv-as-hyperlinks