# How do I write a hyperlink to a CSV File using python?

Tags: python, csv, hyperlink

I would like to write a hyperlink to a CSV file that would look like this in MS Excel:
[image: What It would look like]

I could not find any other solution on Stack Overflow or Google.
Pls help
Thanks

P.S I'm on Python 3.8 on Windows 10

Comment: CSV is a text-only format. Either (1) your screenshot is not a CSV file or (2) Excel is doing some additional work for you. My bet is that it's (1)

Comment: try visiting [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6563091/can-excel-interpret-the-urls-in-my-csv-as-hyperlinks) thread

Comment: FYI, it is a CSV File so i think Excel is doing some extra work. Thanks for the info