# scrapy-xlsx, How to make a clickable link in a xlsx?

Tags: python, scrapy, xlsx

I don't know if my code is responsible for this issue or not.
With this question ([Scapy, Python - To create a clickable link with CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68191047/scapy-python-to-create-a-clickable-link-with-csv?noredirect=1#comment120519161_68191047)), I found out that CSV does not support hyperlink format. So I found the `scrapy-xlsx` package, installed it, and ran it.

```
scrapy crawl GoogleScrapyBot -o output.xlsx
```

Then I can get "output.xlsx".
When I open "output.xlsx" on my PC (Windows 10, Office365), it opens as shown below (the hyperlink is still not set)
[image]

But when I click on the input window in Excel,
[image]

It will be changed to a clickable link.
[image]

I don't want to do this on the Excel program. Is there any possible way in Scrapy?

Comment: I put this in your question about CSV a few hours back: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6563091/can-excel-interpret-the-urls-in-my-csv-as-hyperlinks#8027013

Comment: @barny did you get this to work ? For me, Excel shows "We found a problem with some content, do you want try to recover" ?

Comment: @barny I don't want to do extra work when I open Excel. If I understand correctly about the link you shared, it seems that I need to work on additional Excel programs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add this method in your `GoogleBotsSpider` class. It uses `openpyxl` which is included with `scrapy-xlsx`. Dont forget to add `from openpyxl import load_workbook`.

```
def close(self, reason):
    super().close(self, reason)
    wb = load_workbook(self.settings.attributes["FEED_URI"].value)
    ws = wb.active
    for i, row in enumerate(ws.rows):
        if i:  # ignores first row which contains column headers
            row[0].hyperlink = row[0].value  # here 0 means the first cell of the row, adapt it to your code
            row[0].style = "Hyperlink"
    wb.save(self.settings.attributes["FEED_URI"].value)
```

You also need to add this setting `FEED_URI = "output.xlsx"` in `settings.py` but you could also get it from `sys.argv`.

Comment: Thank you. I think it'll be useful to me. I'll review it and try to fit my code. Before I saw your answer, I tried Pandas, and I checked that the xlsx file was well generated and the link was displayed well displayed.

Comment: I think it's more clear and efficient to do it straight in the spider class. If this was useful to you, please consider upvoting this answer :)